# How remove highlit in restrect pane programtical

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

How can I access the below checkbox programmatically, I make my document protected `Readonly` and some ranges can edit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = True
```

or to switch off:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
```

This is in VBA, but I'm sure you can translate it into your C#:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = 0; // -1
```

ShadeEditableRanges is actually an int in C#

```
int Word.View.ShadeEditableRanges { get; set; }
```